# Can I add nullable column to an existing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I have an existing table. Now I want to add a column to that table whose value might be null. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you can do that just alter that table and add new field with null type and done. It won't impact on existing fields at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply execute the following command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ExistingTable ADD NullableColumnName DataType NULL
```

If the data type is `INT`, and the new column name is `NewColumn`, your command would be;

```sql
ALTER TABLE ExistingTable ADD NewColumn INT NULL
```